# TYPO3 v11: Form Configuration not loading

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

i set up a new TYPO3 project with the new version 11.
Since I need a form on one of my pages, I wanted to configure it within the form configuration. But if I click on "create new form" everything I get is a loading window.

[image: form configuration window]

Has anyone encountered the same error? I went through my error logs but couldn't find any errors there.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that is fixed by the two patches linked in https://forge.typo3.org/issues/93168 . It will be included in the next release.